# Hyperlink inside label field in Vaadin 12

Tags: vaadin, vaadin12

In Vaadin 12, I can't seem to create a hyperlink (or for that matter, any "normal" http entries) inside a label field. It just ends up displaying my commands as text. Here's my code:

```
final Label lblRunMs = new Label("<ol><li>Please now run your mass spectrometer (MS) using the gs-DIA method files built in the previous step.</li><li>While the MS is running, the generated MS files will be automatically and in near real-time imported (eg ~60 seconds after the MS files have been created) imported into the " + Constants.MAIN_APP_NAME + " system.</li> <li>Once one or more of the MS files have been generated by the MS and imported into the " + Constants.MAIN_APP_NAME + " system, you can then move on the next step, namely \"Run " + Constants.MAIN_APP_NAME + " which is the next tab. In that next tab, you can select one or more of those imported MS files to undergo the " + Constants.MAIN_APP_NAME + " processing.</li></ol>");
add(lblRunMs);
```

Based on googling, I can see that earlier version of Vaadin allowed you to specifying ContentMode, as in:

```
Label htmlLabel = new Label(
    "In HTML mode, all HTML formatting tags, such as \n" +
    "<ul>"+
    "  <li><b>bold</b></li>"+
    "  <li>itemized lists</li>"+
    "  <li>etc.</li>"+
    "</ul> "+
    "are preserved.",
    ContentMode.HTML);
```

but that option doesn't seem available in Vaadin 12. What's the "right" way to address this need in Vaadin 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In V10+, the `Label` component maps to a `<label>` HTML tag, which is probably not what you want here. In your example above, using `new Html()` would be more appropriate. For text content, `Span` or `Text` are good options.